# Flask ajax modal

Tags: javascript, ajax, flask, bootstrap-modal

I want to load a page with Bootstrap modal using ajax. Scenario is like,

1. When a button is clicked,
2. The button will call ajax to get data,
3. From flask, it will get related data from DB and return the data in JSON format,
4. In ajax success part, it will dynamically generate modal page and show it up.

I wasn't able to find a good example and I'm getting errors even returning html page.

My sample code runs on

```
<html>
<head>
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="../static/css/jquery.modal.min.css">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="../static/js/jquery.modal.min.js" type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
// Open modal in AJAX callback
$('#manual-ajax').click(function(event) {
  event.preventDefault();
  $.get(this.href, function(html) {
    $(html).appendTo('body').modal();
  });
});
</script>
</head>
<main>
<a href="/ajax2" id="manual-ajax">second example</a>
</main>
</html>
```

and flask part will return

```
@app.route('/ajax2')
def ajax2():
  return app.send_static_file(url_for('static', filename='../templates/ajax2.html'))
```

but it generates 404 error even from beginning. Please help.

Comment: My recommendation would be to break this down into the various components and debug each piece: 1) request HTML from Flask via XHR 2) Bootstrap Modal. Some great modal examples [here](https://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#modals). Both pieces are currently wrong. 404 means you're link is requesting a resource that doesn't exist. You should use the `url_for()` within any link in your HTML template in Flask to avoid this from ever happening. You need to add an actual modal into your template as well, bootstrap doesn't just inject HTML into your page to create a modal... see the examples.

Comment: @PJSantoro Thanks for your comment first of all. Modal doesn't seem to be necessarily implemented with hide feature. If you look at this example, "http://jquerymodal.com/", it dynamically load an external html page as modal. This is something that I want to do. My movie list has lots of movies and when I click each of items, a modal will pop up. I think it'll be more efficient to dynamically load each item in my case... Any idea? Thanks.

Comment: @PJSantoro https://jsfiddle.net/ednon5d1/ This also is another example calling external html file into modal..

Answer (score -2):

You can write: `$('id_body_modal').html(html);
$('id_modal').modal('show');`

Comment: Thanks for comment but I want to load an external html file into modal. Not like this..